# Gdb stl pretty printing without type info

Tags: python, gdb, pretty-print

I'm currently using a python pretty printer obtained using:

```
svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python
```

A typical debug session would look like:

```
(gdb) p some_vector
$1 = std::vector of length 4, capacity 4 = {0, 1, 2, 3}
(gdb) p some_vector[0]
$2 = (__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<unsigned int> >::value_type &) @0x8524f0: 0
```

The thing is, I hardly ever need the type and address information provided, and it often simply reduces readability. Is there an easy way to make it look like the following?

```
(gdb) p some_vector
$1 = {0, 1, 2, 3}
(gdb) p some_vector[0]
$2 = 0
```

Comment: If you use the python `XMethods` as well, it will look the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way to do this.

Since you have your own checkout of the printers, the simplest thing to do is to edit them.  If you edit the `to_string` method of the printer for `std::vector`, you will be able to get the `p some_vector` command working the way you like.

For the second case, the output format is decided internally by gdb.  I think you can suppress the address with `set print address off`, but as far as I know the rest is not configurable.  You could try writing a pretty-printer for the element type here.